# JQuery wont change href depending on computer OS

Tags: jquery, html, href

Sorry guys , need to bring my old question back from the dead as Ive tried to get back into doing jquery - Im not sure if Im linking it wrong in my html side or what.

my Jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1) {
   // Computers runs windows
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").each(function() {
        this.href = this.href.replace("Volumes", "KP01DS0194TG");
    });
  }
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1) {
    // computer is a Mac
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").each(function() {
        this.href = this.href.replace("KP01DS0194TG", "Volumes");
    });
  }
});
```

Ive completely taken the linking out from my html , I pretty much scrapped it.
On Jsfiddle this coding with my html works PERFECTLY not a single hitch .

however when I linked it to my html it would not change.

so if you could please give me some tips - how do I go about linking my file called "jsquery.js" to the html - is that also all I need to link or is there something else (because I read the Jquery website and it said about downloading something from there but it went completely over my head) but yeah help would be amazing!

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/KJdjS/12/  Thats the link

Ninja Edit : when ever I change my html links in my index file to 3 "///" it will not work - it gives me an error , as dreamweaver automatically changes it to 5 "/////" when I add the link - but it auto changes to 2 "//" when I click on the link but on the mac side I need 3 "///"

Comment: please post your jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your codes are in `jsquery.js` file load the files in this order.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry , thats not changing it still

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

assuming jQuery lives in a subfolder (or subpath of your url) on your harddrive (or your server) called "js"

Example layout:

```
/
 some_folder/
             index.html
             js/
                jquery-1.7.2.min.js
```

You would put above `<script>` tag in your index.html file.

Comment: same as I said to raminson , still not changing it.